# problem : Find the number of functions

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A = \{x,y,z,w\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$. How many functions from $A$ to $B$ are not one-to-one?

I think the answer is $\binom 51+\binom 52+\binom 53$; is it right?

Comment: What are C1, C2, and C3?

Comment: Combination. 5C1 ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the total number of functions minus the number that are 1-1: $5^4-5\cdot 4\cdot3\cdot2$.